# pymysql returns perplexing value error

Tags: python, pymysql

I am attempting to write a simple python script to import from a text file to a mysql database, and encounter a perplexing error

Windows 10, Mysql 5.7.18, Python 3.6, pymysql

The contents of the text file:

```
nickname|fullname|cell|email|updatedt
andrew|Andrew Jones|+12395551172|arj@domain.com|2017-05-04 13:26:10
laurelai|Laurelai Smith||lsmith@domain.net|2017-05-04 13:27:47
```

I read in the data to construct a sql string:
    insert into contacts (nickname,fullname,cell,email,updatedt) values(%,%,%,%,%)

The field values to be inserted are read in as follows:
    ['andrew', 'Andrew Jones', '+12395551172', 'arj@domain.com', '2017-05-04 13:26:10']
This is of course a Python list object. I have tried converting it to a tuple, but with same result

The routine to insert the row into the table is as follows:

```
def insert(sql, values):
#insert a single row of data from the input file
    connection = getconn()
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql, values)
        #except ValueError:
            #print('Value error from pymysql')
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

The following ValueError is returned:

ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 69

if, however, I extract the data values and insert them into the sqlstring by concatenation, I get:

```
insert into contacts (nickname,fullname,cell,email,updatedt) values('laurelai','Laurelai Smith','','lsmith@domain.net','2017-05-04 13:27:47')
```

This inserts the rows without error

What causes the ValueError?

Comment: Is `%` the right character to use for parameterized queries?  I'm more used to seeing `%s` or `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your insert query to `%s` instead of `%`:

```
insert into contacts (nickname,fullname,cell,email,updatedt) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

Refer to [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).